# pandas shift does not work for subset of columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data Frame:

`df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5], "b":[3,2,1,2,2], "c": [2,1,0,2,1]})`

```
    a   b   c
0   1   3   2
1   2   2   1
2   3   1   0
3   4   2   2
4   5   2   1
```

and I want to shift columns a and b at indexes 0 to 2. I.e. my desired result is

```
    a   b   c
0  NaN NaN  2
1   1   3   1
2   2   2   0
3   4   1   2
4   5   2   1
```

If I do

`df[["a", "b"]][0:3] = df[["a", "b"]][0:3].shift(1)`

and look at `df`, it appears to not have changed.

However, if a select only the rows or the columns, it works:

**Single Column, select subset of rows:**

`df["a"][0:3] = df["a"][0:3].shift(1)`

Output:

```
     a  b   c
0   NaN 3   2
1   1.0 2   1
2   2.0 1   0
3   4.0 2   2
4   5.0 2   1
```

Likewise, if i select a **list of columns, but all rows**, it works as expected, too:

`df[["a", "b"]] = df[["a", "b"]].shift(1)`

output:

```
    a   b   c
0   NaN NaN 2
1   1.0 3.0 1
2   2.0 2.0 0
3   3.0 1.0 2
4   4.0 2.0 1
```

Why does `df[["a", "b"]][0:3] = df[["a", "b"]][0:3].shift(1)` not work as expected? am I missing something?

Comment: `df[["a", "b"]][0:3]` does not work because you're not indexing properly, and this is not returning a view, you're just updating a copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is there are double selecting - first columns and then rows, so updating copy. Check also [evaluation order matters](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters).

Possible solution with one selecting [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for index labels and columns names:

```
df.loc[0:2, ["a", "b"]] = df.loc[0:2, ["a", "b"]].shift(1)
print (df)
     a    b  c
0  NaN  NaN  2
1  1.0  3.0  1
2  2.0  2.0  0
3  4.0  2.0  2
4  5.0  2.0  1
```

If not default index and is necessary select first 2 rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5], "b":[3,2,1,2,2], "c": [2,1,0,2,1]},
                   index=list('abcde'))

df.loc[df.index[0:2], ["a", "b"]] = df.loc[df.index[0:2], ["a", "b"]].shift(1)
print (df)
     a    b  c
a  NaN  NaN  2
b  1.0  3.0  1
c  3.0  1.0  0
d  4.0  2.0  2
e  5.0  2.0  1
```